# How do I bind the my Router to my method - Backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to bind a method to my Backbone Router.  Here is my class:

```
define(function(require) {
  'use strict';

  var Backbone = require('backbone');
  var Header = require('views/header.view');
  var MainBody = require('views/main.body.view');

  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    currentView: null,
    routes: {
      "about": "about"
    },

    initialize: function() {
      Backbone.on('location', this.test);
      debugger;
      _.bindAll(this, 'test');
    },

    about: function() {
      var header = new Header();
      $('#header').html(header.render().el);
    },

    test: function(data) {
      this.currentView.close();
    }
  });

  return Router;
});
```

In the initialize block I am attempting to bind `this` to `test`.  When I call the `test` function, my `this` is still `Backbone` and not the current class.  What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding it after you attach the handler.

```
initialize: function() {
    // `test` is bound with the wrong THIS
    Backbone.on('location', this.test);
    debugger;
    // Here you actually do the binding
    _.bindAll(this, 'test');
 },
```

Just swap the order and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: That didn't fix the problem.  Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Hmm. Well you're passing the original test function as a handler for the `location` event. The 'this' for that function will be whatever object invokes it. Afterwards, _.bindAll create a new, bounded function for the specified object that is different from the one you passed. So it should come first, which is why I thought that was the issue.

Comment: Do you have the test method attached anywhere else? And have you tried this: http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this

Answer (score 1):

I think you need third parameter while calling [Backbone.on](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on)

> To supply a context value for this when the callback is invoked, pass the optional third argument: `model.on('change', this.render, this)`

Like this `Backbone.on('location', this.test, this);`